# Return an array with method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a doubt.
I am developing the following code which will be a multplication table for a number that you manually introduce. What I cannot get is to print the table. I don't know what is going on because as far as I know, all the code is right written.

```
public class Tabla 
{

public static void main (String[] args) 
{        
    int n=4;       

    Tabla table = new Tabla ();
    int dato [];
    dato=table.producto(n);        

    for (int j=1;j<=10;j++)
    {System.out.println(dato[j]);}

}



public int [] producto(int num) 
{ 
    int a[]={'0'};

    for (int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {a[i]=num*i;}

    return a;


}    

}
```

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!

**I changed the code to:

```
public class Tabla 
{

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {        
        int n=4;       
        int j;

        Tabla table = new Tabla ();
        int dato[]=new int [10];
        dato=table.producto(n);        

        for (j=0;j<10;j++)
        {System.out.println(dato[j]);
        }

    }



    public int [] producto(int num) 
    { 
        // make a 10-element array
        int a[] = new int[10];

       // fill up the array with products
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {a[i] = num * (i+1); }

        return a;            

    }       
}
```

Works like a charm!
Now I am wondering why the compiler threw the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" when I had the for cycle as  `for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)`

Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: The following appears:
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at tabla.Tabla.producto(Tabla.java:31)
 at tabla.Tabla.main(Tabla.java:17)
Java Result: 1
GENERACIÓN CORRECTA (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @MikePérez I fixed my code, so it should no longer throw any out-of-range exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building off of Wasserman's answer, what you should have written is as follows:

```
public int[] producto(int num) 
{
    // make a 10-element array
    int a[] = new int[10];

    // fill up the array with products
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        a[i] = num * (i + 1);

    return a;
}
```

You created a single-element array, whereas you wanted a 10-element array to fill up.

Comment: This will still throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh, sorry! My mistake! I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

```
int a[]={'0'};
```

This line creates an array `a` with only one element -- not the 11 you're trying to fill -- and moreover, that one element is the ASCII code for the character `0`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the integer variables but nothing happens yet... Any idea why?

Comment: @MikePérez take a look at my answer. Does that work?

Comment: No, I have no idea why, because I have no idea what you've changed.  Post your updated code.

Comment: @LouisWasserman isn't Mike Pérez making a 10-element array, not 11 elements?

Comment: @feralin: Reread the `for` loop.

Comment: He is not trying to fill up 11 elements. It may be easier to _create_ 11 elements, so that element generation can be 1-based, but he still only generates 10 elements.